# Read in non-standard JSON format with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a file filled with JSON-objects that I want to read in. Unfortunately, the format is a bit non-standard: There are messages that are base64-encoded and some that aren't. The messages that aren't encoded contain another JSON object, which unfortunately includes newlines as well. This messes up reading in the files "the standard way" (spark.read.json("my_file.json")).

The file looks like this:

```
{"Timestamp":"2022-05-14T00:28:00.2440000Z","Properties":{"connectionDeviceId":"ID1"},"Body":"WWBxssBase64gibberish"}\n
{"Timestamp":"2022-05-14T00:29:14.4700000Z","Properties":{"connectionDeviceId":"ID2"},"Body":[\n
{\n
    "more":"Info",\n
    "but":"already",\n
    "decoded":"!"\n
}\n
]\n
}\n
{"Timestamp":"2022-05-14T00:28:00.2440000Z","Properties":{"connectionDeviceId":"ID1"},"Body":"XxeNiceBodymessageinBase64again"}\n
```

With the format like this I can't use newline as a linesep.

Is there a good way to cut the file into lines based on opened and closed curly braces? Or how would I write my own parser for that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic that I can find is to use `ast.literal_eval`

This clubbed together with a try except block can be used to reverse engineer the fact the structures will be correct when continous.

The following is a brief implementation for the same.

###### Note : Using yield gives you a good speed advantage.

```py
string="""{"Timestamp":"2022-05-14T00:28:00.2440000Z","Properties":{"connectionDeviceId":"ID1"},"Body":"WWBxssBase64gibberish"}\n
{"Timestamp":"2022-05-14T00:29:14.4700000Z","Properties":{"connectionDeviceId":"ID2"},"Body":[\n
{\n
    "more":"Info",\n
    "but":"already",\n
    "decoded":"!"\n
}\n
]\n
}\n
{"Timestamp":"2022-05-14T00:28:00.2440000Z","Properties":{"connectionDeviceId":"ID1"},"Body":"XxeNiceBodymessageinBase64again"}\n"""


from ast import literal_eval


def yield_correct_structs(string):
    local_builder = ""
    for s in string.splitlines():
        try:
            x = literal_eval(s)
            yield x
        except:
            local_builder = local_builder + s
            try:
                x = literal_eval(local_builder)
                yield x
            except:
                continue
for e in yield_correct_structs(string):
    print(type(e), e)
```

Output :

```
<class 'dict'> {'Timestamp': '2022-05-14T00:28:00.2440000Z', 'Properties': {'connectionDeviceId': 'ID1'}, 'Body': 'WWBxssBase64gibberish'}
<class 'dict'> {'Timestamp': '2022-05-14T00:29:14.4700000Z', 'Properties': {'connectionDeviceId': 'ID2'}, 'Body': [{'more': 'Info', 'but': 'already', 'decoded': '!'}]}
<class 'dict'> {'Timestamp': '2022-05-14T00:29:14.4700000Z', 'Properties': {'connectionDeviceId': 'ID2'}, 'Body': [{'more': 'Info', 'but': 'already', 'decoded': '!'}]}
<class 'dict'> {'Timestamp': '2022-05-14T00:28:00.2440000Z', 'Properties': {'connectionDeviceId': 'ID1'}, 'Body': 'XxeNiceBodymessageinBase64again'}
```